# Returning performance counter results from within a job

Tags: powershell, perfmon

I have the following script running a performance counter from within a job:

```
$counter = {
  param($TestLength)
  $perfsample = Get-Counter -Counter `
  "\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Time",`
  "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",`
  "\Process(_Total)\Working Set",`
  "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/Sec"`
  -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples $TestLength -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  $perfsample
}

Start-Job -Name GettingCounters -ScriptBlock $counter -ArgumentList $TestLength | Wait-Job

Export-Counter -Path $DestinationFile -FileFormat csv -InputObject (Receive-Job GettingCounters)
```

When running the above code, I am presented with the following error:

```
Export-Counter : Cannot bind parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the "Micro
soft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSampleSet" value of type
"Deserialized.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSample
Set" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSample
Set".
```

I understand that this is due to the output being serialized, so would it be possible to return a deserialized output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All types aren't serializable unfortunately. Why not just export the inside the job?

```
$counter = {
  param($TestLength, $DestinationFile)
  $perfsample = Get-Counter -Counter `
  "\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Time",`
  "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",`
  "\Process(_Total)\Working Set",`
  "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/Sec"`
  -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples $TestLength -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  $perfsample | Export-Counter -Path $DestinationFile -FileFormat csv
}

Start-Job -Name GettingCounters -ScriptBlock $counter -ArgumentList $TestLength, $DestinationFile | Wait-Job
```

As an alternative, you could use runspaces instead of jobs as they don't require object serialization and are usually faster (at least when you use a RunspacePool to run multiple threads in parrallel). A few more lines to use it though:

```
$DestinationFile = ".\Desktop\test.csv"
$TestLength = 10

$counter = {
  param($TestLength)
  $perfsample = Get-Counter -Counter `
  "\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Time",`
  "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",`
  "\Process(_Total)\Working Set",`
  "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/Sec"`
  -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples $TestLength -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  $perfsample
}

$Powershell = [powershell]::Create()
$Powershell.AddScript($counter)
$Powershell.AddParameter("TestLength",$TestLength)
$job = $Powershell.BeginInvoke()

#Get results
$result = $Powershell.EndInvoke($job)
$result | Export-Counter -Path $DestinationFile -FileFormat csv

#Cleanup
$Powershell.Dispose()
$Powershell = $null
$job = $null
```